# Set password when power my PI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, security, passwords

At now when I connect to my PI with VNC, then PI ask password. The user is pi.

If I logout and if want to use again pi, then I have to login again with the same password which I use with VNC. The user is pi.

[image]

BUT when plug in my raspberry PI it automatically login to the account. How can I set a password to asking password?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the workflow you describe, when you disconnect VNC, your user is clearly being logged out, or specifically, the device is being locked.

Comment: @Ramhound you misunderstand me. Sorry for not perfect description. I wanted to illustrate with 2 examples (vnc and after logout) when the raspberry asks password. So in these 2 cases the 'security' works fine. BUT when I power up = plug in my raspberry, then raspberry starts the system and it does not asks password from me and it lets me in. Thats what I want to change.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify your question instead of using a comment

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default setting by `raspi-config`

```
sudo raspi-config
```

`1 System Options` -> `S5 Boot / Auto Login` -> select `B3 Desktop`, after reboot you will be prompted for password.